# To make a button from SCLAlertView in iOS as we write in alert view textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make a button through SCLAlertView in iOS as I am writing a text in alert and button is to be generated but I usually gets previous buttons which are made by me in array bubbleStringArray , I am not able to add new buttons in view for this view i am using another library BubbleButtonView.

```html
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
bubbleStringArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:40];

    bubbleStringArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hello", @"this", @"is", @"a", @"test", @"of", @"the", @"BubbleButtonView", @"class", @"Each", @"one", @"of", @"these", @"is", @"a", @"button",nil];
    //[arraybuttons addObjectsFromArray:bubbleStringArray];
    [bubbleStringArray addObjectsFromArray:apdel.sendArray];
    //[bubbleStringArray addObjectsFromArray:addarray];
    UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:51/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:254/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:235/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    //buttons generated
    [bubbleView fillBubbleViewWithButtons:bubbleStringArray bgColor:bgColor textColor:textColor fontSize:14];
}


- (IBAction)addButtons:(id)sender {
    SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];

    UITextField *textField = [alert addTextField:@"Enter your name"];
    arraybuttons=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //[arraybuttons addObjectsFromArray:apdel.bubbleStringArray];
    [alert addButton:@"Ok" actionBlock:^(void) {

        [arraybuttons addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text]];
        [bubbleStringArray addObjectsFromArray:arraybuttons];
        NSLog(@"%@",arraybuttons);
        NSLog(@"%@",bubbleStringArray);
        UIColor *textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:47/255.0 blue:51/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:254/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:235/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        //buttons generated
        [bubbleView fillBubbleViewWithButtons:apdel.bubbleStringArray bgColor:bgColor textColor:textColor fontSize:14];

    }];
        [alert showEdit:self title:kInfoTitle subTitle:kSubtitle closeButtonTitle:kButtonTitle duration:0.0f];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

arraybuttons isn't allocated in the action block. Try

```
 [bubbleStringArray addObject:textfield.text];
```

instead of

```
   [arraybuttons addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text]];
    [bubbleStringArray addObjectsFromArray:arraybuttons];
```

PS What is apdel.bubbleStringArray ?